# What should I do when the factor $a_n$ in a power series is a series itself?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

We were given the following exercise:

> calculate the convergence radius of the following series and examine their behaviour on the edge of their respective convergence circles:
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\frac 1{8}+\frac 1{27}+\ldots+\frac 1{n^{3}})x^n$$
> $$\sum \frac {x^{n^2}}{2^n}$$

now correct me if I'm wrong, but you can calculate a power series' convergence radius by converting it to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (x-x_0)^n$, where $x_0$ is the centre of the convergence circle. The convergence radius $r$ can then be calculated with $\frac1{r}=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$. But In the first series, $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac 1{k^3}$ is a series itself. How should I go about solving this exercise? 
Also, does "examining their behaviour on the edge of their respective convergence circles" mean I should see if the series has a limit for $n \to (x_0-r)$ and $n \to (x_0+r)$? 
 Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Even if $a_n$ is a series itself, it still is some constant depending on $n$ (basically, doesn't involve $x$), so the well definition of the power series is not a problem. As for its radius of convergence, think about whether the series $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k^3}$ is convergent or not. If it is, then are not $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ cosying up to each other too much for large $n$? (Also, you are right about the edges part : once you get the radius of convergence, we don't know if convergence occurs or not at the end points $x_0 \pm r$ so these need to be checked individually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using formulae to calculate the radius of convergence is misguided, and that the comparison test is in general a better way to proceed.

Let $a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^3}$, and consider the series $\sum_n a_n x^n$ whose radius of convergence is $R$.

Case (i) $x>1$. We have that $a_n x^n >x^n$, and $\sum x^n$ is divergent; so by comparison  $\sum a_n  x^n$ is also divergent. Hence $R\leqslant 1$.

Case (ii) $x<1$. Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}$ is convergent, to $S$ say. Then the sequence $a_n$ is monotone increasing and bounded by $S$. Hence for each $x$ we have that $a_n x^n < Sx^n$. Now for such $x$ the series $\sum Sx^n$ is convergent, and so by comparison $\sum a_n  x^n$ is also convergent. Hence $R\geqslant 1$.

That is, the radius of convergence is $1$.

It remains to discuss convergence on the circle of convergence. As $|a_n x^n|=a_n$, and $a_n\not\to 0$, the series can't converge at these points.

Your second series can also be done by comparison.

Comment: I understand the approach, and it really does seem much easier than using the formulae. But what I don't understand is how $R >= 1$ suggest $R = 1$. Do we have to assume the smallest possible diameter for the convergence circle?

Comment: I've shown both $R\leqslant 1$ and $R\geqslant 1$.

Comment: oh wait, you're right. I'm dumb. Sorry for that. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I want to be extra sure that I fully understand this (since the exam is coming up in 2 weeks). Isn't $\sum (-x)^n = \sum x^n (-1)^n$ divergent? How is it then that $\sum S(-x)^n$ is convergent?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have said $0<x<1$ so I am always looking at non-negative $x$. As indeed is all we need to do in this case. But your GP does converge for $|x|<1$ surely. Basically what I am using are these facts: If $an x_0^n$ converges then $R\geqslant |x_0|$; if $an x_0^n$ diverges then $R< |x_0|$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably to use *Hadamard's formula*:

$$\frac 1 R=\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n\vphantom{b}}=\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n\vphantom{b}}.$$
Observe that
$$1<a_n <\zeta(3),\quad\text{ so }\quad 1 < \sqrt[n]{a_n} <\sqrt[n]{\zeta(3)}.$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: I'll try and get back to you if I can't.

Comment: what is $\zeta$ referring to?

Comment: The sum of the series defined  by the coefficients here. Riemann's zeta function is defined, for an integer $k$, by $\;\zeta(k)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^k}$. $\zeta(3)\approx 1.20$ (it was proved by Apery that it is an irrational number).